# Render Element HTML as plain text

Tags: python, html, django, xml, web-scraping

I'm building a template tag in Django that returns HTML, I'm using the Element object to build the tree.
Is there a way to render the tree as plain HTML?

in my template i have something like {% build foo=bar %}
build returns an Element, i cant find a way to render it and insert that Element into my HTML doc.

Answer (score 1):

yeah there's a simple template tag you can use called "safe". You can use it like this:

```
{{ "<p>some HTML</p>"|safe }}
```

It will render as HTML